# Is there way to add "Loading screen" when DOM rendering in Next.js app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to turn on loading screen when DOM is loading. In pure react i did it by adding another div with loading-screen in /public/index.html and disabling it when last element loaded. How to achive it in Next.js app?

Answer (score 0):

To achive this, I render my loader inside body tag in `_document.js` file.
I thought a bit how to detect moment when all of my page content loaded (content, images, fonts, styles) and i got idea to load my fonts in footer, after all content, images and styles are loaded.
I did it, by implementing `useEffect()` hook in my footer file, and load fonts like this:

```
const Footer = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let fonts = [];
    if (typeof window !== "undefinded") {
      // Initialize Font
      fonts.push(
        new FontFace("font1", "url(/fonts/font1.ttf)", {
          style: "normal",
          weight: "400",
        })
      );
      fonts.push(
        new FontFace("font2", "url(/fonts/font2.ttf)", {
          style: "bold",
          weight: "700",
        })
      );

      // Load all fonts
      for (var font in fonts) {
        document.fonts.add(font);
        font.load();
      }
      // Disable loading screen when all font are loaded
      document.fonts.ready.then(function (e) {
        document.getElementById("loading-screen").style.display = "none";
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return <>...Footer content</>;
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).